# Can anyone tell why this graphic glitch occurs on my laptop runnning Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, graphics, display, intel-graphics

[A picture of the distorted display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p70De.jpg)

I have a HP elitebook G1 850. It has the default intel graphics. I had Ubuntu 16.04 before doing a fresh installation of 18.04 but that did not solve the issue. This just randomly happens and the only way to solve is to turn off the display and then turn it on again, or put the laptop to sleep and login again. Can anyone help me find out what's causing it and lead to some possible solutions?